# mysql command to display table tuples according to the date

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables which displays the contents of the tables according to the table,

1. I have two table product and sales
2. pcode is the primary key for product and foreign key to sales.
3. I need to display sales according to the particular days sale.

**My Query is :**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT product.pcode,pname,brand,price,oldbal,receipt,total,current,sales.date FROM product,sales WHERE sales.date='$date' AND product.pcode=sales.pcode");
```

this displays only product which was sold on that particular day, I need to display all product from product table  and if they are sold they should display the data or null if its not.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is known as `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT product.pcode,pname,brand,price,oldbal,receipt,total,current,sales.date
FROM product LEFT JOIN sales
ON product.pcode=sales.pcode
WHERE sales.date=$date
```

Comment: this was also useful. I don't know whom to tick. both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT product.pcode,pname,brand,price,oldbal,receipt,total,current,sales.date FROM product LEFT JOIN sales ON product.pcode = sales.pcode WHERE sales.date='$date';
```